# Ffmpeg dynamic cropping for every frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have different crop parameters for every frame. I was using sendcmd but apparently, that is not working.

This is the format of my sendcmd file

```
0.00 crop 'w=466:h=432:x=1373:y=336';
0.02 crop 'w=324:h=382:x=277:y=693';
0.03 crop 'w=304:h=332:x=1364:y=794';
0.05 crop 'w=348:h=448:x=1500:y=966';
0.07 crop 'w=466:h=412:x=794:y=193';
0.08 crop 'w=390:h=502:x=1425:y=813';
```

And I am running this command

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 1 -i Demo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=crop_parameters.txt[video]" -map "[video]" output_%03d.png
```

These are the logs coming from FFmpeg

```
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] [expr] interval #0 start_ts:0.000000 end_ts:9223372036854.775391 ts:0.083367
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] [expr] interval #1 start_ts:0.040000 end_ts:9223372036854.775391 ts:0.083367
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] [enter+expr] interval #2 start_ts:0.080000 end_ts:9223372036854.775391 ts:0.083367
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Processing command #0 target:crop command:w arg:147
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Command reply for command #0: ret:Function not implemented res:
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Processing command #1 target:crop command:h arg:258
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Command reply for command #1: ret:Function not implemented res:
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Processing command #2 target:crop command:x arg:928
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Command reply for command #2: ret:Function not implemented res:
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Processing command #3 target:crop command:y arg:102
[Parsed_sendcmd_0 @ 0x6000016709a0] Command reply for command #3: ret:Function not implemented res:
```

It resulted in no cropping of the video, it just gives the exact same frame